# Extract Elm runtime into separate chunk

Tags: webpack, elm, webpack-2

When an Elm file is compiled, the Elm runtime gets extracted into the same file. Let's call this file `app.js` from now on. When even one single byte is changed in `app.js`, the hash changes, resulting in the client to download the file all over again, even though only one byte changed. Is there a way to extract the Elm runtime into a separate `vendor` (or `commons`) chunk?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do that. There's a way to compile and add more modules into app.js. Webpack actually feels slower than Elm so you would be losing performance by trying to do chunking with webpack. It's a good question though, it would be nice to ship as a separate chunk through the `elm make`

Comment: @RudolfOlah Moving the Elm runtime to a separate chunk is more something for a production build. It just feels right to put the runtime in the vendor code as well as for the caching reasons I stated.

Comment: yeah I agree on that point however with Elm it seems like the performance is better. I wonder how the companies using Elm in production are deploying it, I wonder if they use webpack or something else.

Comment: My understanding is that as of 0.18 this is not possible. 0.19 is aimed more at concerns like this one so probably stay tuned for that release (I don't know of any ETA on it unfortunately).

Comment: I posted a **potential** workaround, will be testing it later today with multiple Elm-compiled JS files to make sure it does work but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 5):

In Elm 0.18 and previous versions, the core of Elm is included with every bundle.

This can be inefficient, for example if you're loading different Elm components on multiple pages. Each page would need its own bundle generated but the Elm core would be included with each bundle.

## Workaround (untested!)

1. Compile your Elm code into a bundle, `output.js`
2. Open `output.js` and starting from the beginning of the file up until the last `var` declaration that looks something like this:

   ```
   var _elm_lang$html$Html_Events$Options = F2(
   ```

   Below that last variable declaration that starts with `_elm_lang` you should see the code for the module that *you* wrote. That's where the separation begins.
3. Copy and paste that whole chunk into a separate file and name it `elm-core.js`
4. Tada! You should now be able to load them like this in your HTML files:

   ```
    <html>
    <script src="elm-core.js"></script>
    <script src="output.js"></script>
    </html>
   ```

**Beware! The whole output bundle is wrapped in an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) so you will have to wrap all of the chunks in that to make sure it works.** If you don't then you will get errors like "F2 is not defined" and "A2 is undefined".

## Elm 0.19+

In future versions of Elm there should be a nicer solution to this problem.